# Combine two options in offcanvas in UIkit

Tags: javascript, getuikit

I use [offcanvas](https://getuikit.com/docs/offcanvas). I want to use `flip: true` and `mode: push` but the combination of two options does not work. I tried comma separated options:

```
<a href="#offcanvas-slide" class="uk-align-right uk-button uk-button-default" uk-toggle>Menu</a>

<div id="offcanvas-slide" uk-offcanvas="mode: push, flip: true">
```

How can I pass two or more options to offcanvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **";"** to add 2 or more offcanvas to apply in your uk-offcanvas.

```
Below is the sample for your clarification:
```

**https://codepen.io/santhoshsri2002/pen/MPLpYQ**